# "Error loading page" in intel XDK

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

This is my html-js page code

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '#mainpage', function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login").click(function () {
            $.mobile.changePage("#authpage", {
                transition: "slide",
                changeHash: false
            });
        });
    });
    var uri2 = 'api/CEP/AuthenticateUser'

        function find() {

            var userid = $('#UserID').val();
            var pass = $('#Password').val();
            var reqType = $('#RequestType').val();

            var data = {
                strUser: userid,
                strPassword: pass,
                strReqType: reqType
            };

            $.getJSON(uri2, data)

                .done(function (data) {
                $('#User').text(formatItem2(data));
            })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#User').text('Error: ' + err);
            });

        }

        function formatItem2(item2) {
            return 'Emp ID: ' + item2.EmpID + '  RequestType: ' + item2.ResultMsg + '  Name: ' + item2.EmpName;
        }
```

```html
<div id="authpage" data-role="page">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <a href="#mainpage" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a> 
        <h3>
        LOGIN
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_5 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
        <label class="narrow-control label-inline">UserID</label>
        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Your UserID" type="text" id="UserID">
        <label class="narrow-control label-inline">Password</label>
        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Your UserID" type="Password" id="Password">
        <label class="narrow-control label-inline">RequestType</label>
        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Your UserID" type="text" id="RequestType">
        <a class="widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" id="btnclk" href="newpage" onclick="find();">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-iscroll>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="authlist" data-divider-theme="b"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elaborate on your question.

Comment: hi i am new at intel XDK. whenever i call any webmethods or fetch json data it will show error loading page messege at top of emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You may be restricted from making your request through the "browser" due to cross-origin restrictions on the remote server put in place to prevent abuse.  Intel has provided libraries to circumvent these restrictions and allow access, just include these in your app's header:

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script src="xhr.js"></script>
```

More information on how to access JSON from your hybrid app is available here: 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

If you are still having problems, try skipping $.getJSON and try experimenting directly with the getRemoteDataExt method, with an accompanying event listener:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493009

Answer (score 0):

You do not need xhr.js anymore unless you are doing "legacy" builds and NOT cordova.  Ajax calls should work fine and in the Cordova containers are better to use then getRemoteData(Ext).

If you can post a better example, I'll be happy to test it.  Try putting a setup in jsbin that I can test in the Intel® XDK.